# How do i fetch the name of the location and not the code from JSON using autofill dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file like this

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "psgc_code": "010000000",
  "region_name": "Region I (Ilocos Region)",
  "region_code": "01"
}
```

I want to get the `region_name` and save it to the database. I'm fairly new to javascript and this is the code:

```js
var my_handlers = {
  // fill province
  fill_provinces: function() {
    //selected region
    var region_code = $(this).val();

    // set selected text to input
    var region_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let region_input = $('#region-text');
    region_input.val(region_text);
    //clear province & city & barangay input
    $('#province-text').val('');
    $('#city-text').val('');
    $('#barangay-text').val('');

    //province
    let dropdown = $('#province');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose State/Province</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    //city
    let city = $('#city');
    city.empty();
    city.append('<option selected="true" disabled></option>');
    city.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    //barangay
    let barangay = $('#barangay');
    barangay.empty();
    barangay.append('<option selected="true" disabled></option>');
    barangay.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    // filter & fill
    var url = 'ph-json/province.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var result = data.filter(function(value) {
        return value.region_code == region_code;
      });

      result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.province_name.localeCompare(b.province_name);
      });

      $.each(result, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.province_code).text(entry.province_name));
      })
    });
  },
  // fill city
  fill_cities: function() {
    //selected province
    var province_code = $(this).val();

    // set selected text to input
    var province_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let province_input = $('#province-text');
    province_input.val(province_text);
    //clear city & barangay input
    $('#city-text').val('');
    $('#barangay-text').val('');

    //city
    let dropdown = $('#city');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose city/municipality</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    //barangay
    let barangay = $('#barangay');
    barangay.empty();
    barangay.append('<option selected="true" disabled></option>');
    barangay.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    // filter & fill
    var url = 'ph-json/city.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var result = data.filter(function(value) {
        return value.province_code == province_code;
      });

      result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.city_name.localeCompare(b.city_name);
      });

      $.each(result, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.city_code).text(entry.city_name));
      })
    });
  },
  // fill barangay
  fill_barangays: function() {
    // selected barangay
    var city_code = $(this).val();

    // set selected text to input
    var city_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let city_input = $('#city-text');
    city_input.val(city_text);
    //clear barangay input
    $('#barangay-text').val('');

    // barangay
    let dropdown = $('#barangay');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose barangay</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    // filter & Fill
    var url = 'ph-json/barangay.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var result = data.filter(function(value) {
        return value.city_code == city_code;
      });

      result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.brgy_name.localeCompare(b.brgy_name);
      });

      $.each(result, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.brgy_code).text(entry.brgy_name));
      })
    });
  },
  onchange_barangay: function() {
    // set selected text to input
    var barangay_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let barangay_input = $('#barangay-text');
    barangay_input.val(barangay_text);
  },
};

$(function() {
  // events
  $('#region').on('change', my_handlers.fill_provinces);
  $('#province').on('change', my_handlers.fill_cities);
  $('#city').on('change', my_handlers.fill_barangays);
  $('#barangay').on('change', my_handlers.onchange_barangay);

  // load region
  let dropdown = $('#region');
  dropdown.empty();
  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Region</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  const url = 'ph-json/region.json';
  
  // Populate dropdown with list of regions
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, entry) {
      dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.region_code).text(entry.region_name));
    })
  });
});
```

And this is the dropdown i use:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Region *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="region" class="form-control form-control-md" id="region"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="region_text" id="region-text" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Province *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="province" class="form-control form-control-md" id="province"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="province_text" id="province-text" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">City / Municipality *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="city" class="form-control form-control-md" id="city"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="city_text" id="city-text" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Barangay *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="barangay" class="form-control form-control-md" id="barangay"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="barangay_text" id="barangay-text" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do i get the name to save in the database? Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried putting the selected value of the dropdown into the hidden input and it still saves the code and not the name.

**simplified example:** (with json data as object at the end of the file)

```js
var my_handlers = {
  // fill province
  fill_provinces: function() {
    //selected region
    var region_code = $(this).val();

    // set selected text to input
    var region_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let region_input = $('#region-text');
    region_input.val(region_text);
    //clear province & city & barangay input
    $('#province-text').val('');
    $('#city-text').val('');
    $('#barangay-text').val('');

    //province
    let dropdown = $('#province');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose State/Province</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    //city
    let city = $('#city');
    city.empty();
    city.append('<option selected="true" disabled></option>');
    city.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    //barangay
    let barangay = $('#barangay');
    barangay.empty();
    barangay.append('<option selected="true" disabled></option>');
    barangay.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    // filter & fill
    var url = 'ph-json/province.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var result = data.filter(function(value) {
        return value.region_code == region_code;
      });

      result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.province_name.localeCompare(b.province_name);
      });

      $.each(result, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.province_code).text(entry.province_name));
      });
    });
  },
  // fill city
  fill_cities: function() {
    //selected province
    var province_code = $(this).val();

    // set selected text to input
    var province_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let province_input = $('#province-text');
    province_input.val(province_text);
    //clear city & barangay input
    $('#city-text').val('');
    $('#barangay-text').val('');

    //city
    let dropdown = $('#city');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose city/municipality</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    //barangay
    let barangay = $('#barangay');
    barangay.empty();
    barangay.append('<option selected="true" disabled></option>');
    barangay.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    // filter & fill
    var url = 'ph-json/city.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var result = data.filter(function(value) {
        return value.province_code == province_code;
      });

      result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.city_name.localeCompare(b.city_name);
      });

      $.each(result, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.city_code).text(entry.city_name));
      });
    });
  },
  // fill barangay
  fill_barangays: function() {
    // selected barangay
    var city_code = $(this).val();

    // set selected text to input
    var city_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let city_input = $('#city-text');
    city_input.val(city_text);
    //clear barangay input
    $('#barangay-text').val('');

    // barangay
    let dropdown = $('#barangay');
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose barangay</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);

    // filter & Fill
    var url = 'ph-json/barangay.json';
    
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      var result = data.filter(function(value) {
        return value.city_code == city_code;
      });

      result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.brgy_name.localeCompare(b.brgy_name);
      });

      $.each(result, function(key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.brgy_code).text(entry.brgy_name));
      });
    });
  },
  onchange_barangay: function() {
    // set selected text to input
    var barangay_text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    let barangay_input = $('#barangay-text');
    barangay_input.val(barangay_text);
  }
};

$(function() {
  // events
  $('#region').on('change', my_handlers.fill_provinces);
  $('#province').on('change', my_handlers.fill_cities);
  $('#city').on('change', my_handlers.fill_barangays);
  $('#barangay').on('change', my_handlers.onchange_barangay);

  // load region
  let dropdown = $('#region');
  dropdown.empty();
  dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Region</option>');
  dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  
  const region_json = {
    "id": 1,
    "psgc_code": "010000000",
    "region_name": "Region I (Ilocos Region)",
    "region_code": "01"
  };
  
  // Populate dropdown with list of regions
  $.each(region_json, function(key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.region_code).text(entry.region_name));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Region *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="region" class="form-control form-control-md" id="region"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="region_text" id="region-text" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Province *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="province" class="form-control form-control-md" id="province"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="province_text" id="province-text" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">City / Municipality *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="city" class="form-control form-control-md" id="city"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="city_text" id="city-text" required>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Barangay *</label>
  <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
  
  <div class="col-sm-7">
    <select name="barangay" class="form-control form-control-md" id="barangay"></select>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-md" name="barangay_text" id="barangay-text" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You wrote "I have a json file like this" - but in your code you call 4 different JSON files. Could you add them?

Comment: I can't add the other json files because it's too many data in those files. My question would be too long.

Comment: I converted your code to a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) and used your example json data at the end of your js code as an object instead the here not usable url. Please watch it and add the other JSON parts as objects, similar to the region json data, to provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)